# Antd InputNumber (7.1.4v) not allowing to enter 0

Tags: antd

I have required field validation for InputNumber .But if we enter 0, it is converted to empty and validation error is thrown .Please let me know how can I avoid this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check following InputNumber example (working)

```
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Form, InputNumber, Button } from 'antd';

const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = (values) => {
  console.log('Success:', values);
 };

const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
  console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
};

return (
 <Form
   onFinish={onFinish}
   onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
   autoComplete="off"
 >
  <Form.Item
    label="Number"
    name="number"
    rules={[
      {
        required: true,
        message: 'Please enter your number!',
      },
    ]}
  >
    <InputNumber />
  </Form.Item>

  <Form.Item>
    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
      Submit
    </Button>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
);
}

export default Demo;
```

You can also use min and max

```
    <InputNumber min={1} max={10} defaultValue={5} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rule where just numbers are allowed.

```
<Form.Item
style={style.formItemStyle}
labelCol={{ span: 24 }}
label="Postcode"
name="postcode"              
rules={[
  {
    required: true,
    message: "Required Field",
  },
  {
    pattern: /^[0-9]*$/,
    message: "Only Numbers",
  },     
]}              
>
<Input
  style={style.formIputStyle}                       
  placeholder="6160"                                        
/>
```

</Form.Item>

hope that helps